# node js express redirect https to https www

Tags: node.js, express

I found many questions about url redirection, but maybe my case is a little bit different. I need to redirect https://example.com to https://www.example.com, to avoid the "Your connection is not private" screen.

I tried this suggestion bellow, but did not worked with a too many redirections log ...

```
app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.headers.host.slice(0, 3) != 'www') {
        res.redirect('https://www.' + req.headers.host + req.url, 301);
    } else {
       next();
    }
});
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, would comment instead of answer but don't have enough points yet. :(

a) How are you deploying this? 
b) Why are you using this method?

I guess I don't understand - you typically want to have your host like goDaddy or any other host to do the `www` redirecting on their end. It's technically a subdomain.

Almost always when I deploy `http` to `https` I let something like `nginx` or `apache` do the work or the `https` redirection it handles the ssl certificate.

I think a little more information would be helpful.

Comment: Hi Holly. Thanks for your time too. Sorry for the lack of information. I solved it by setting the dns provider correctly.

Comment: Thank you @A.Fujita!! Those words aren’t said enough on this platform. :) Glad you solved it!

Answer (score 0):

You may check before redirecting the all requests. Just redirect only the requests from `http`.  Don't confuse with `URL` regex.

```
app.use (function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.secure) {
            next()
    } else {
            res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url);
    }
});`
```

Comment: Hi Jana, thanks for your time. I think I was not clear enough. My issue is not about redirecting http to https. But anyway, I solved it by setting the dns.